# Airflow | Python question | calling operator within python operator

Tags: python, airflow

I am trying to achieve this using Airflow / Python.

1. Get a rowcount from xcom.pull eg. 100000
2. Use rowcount in a for loop and call two operators

- Create table in database by calling BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator for 20000 records
- create file based on table above into GCS bucket using BigQueryToGCSOperator
- Complete the loop with 20K records

```
def _get_rowcount(ti):

    table_size = 1000000

    rowcount = ti.xcom_pull(key='row_count', task_ids='_bq_result')
    print('BQ rowcount is:', rowcount[0][0])    
    
    for x in range(0,rowcount[0][0],table_size):
        print('Iteration is:', x)
     
        SQL =  f"Create or Replace table <project_id>.<dataset>.<table_name> as select * from `<project_id>.<dataset>.<table_name>` where row_count > {x} and row_count <= { (table_size + x)} "
        print ("SQL: " + SQL)

        task3 = BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator(
            task_id = f"create_tmp_table_{x}",
            use_legacy_sql = False,
            sql = SQL,
            gcp_conn_id = GCP_CONN_ID
        )

        task3.execute(dict())

task2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id = '_get_rowcount',
    provide_context = True,
    python_callable = _get_rowcount,
    dag = dag
    )

task2
```

I have removed BigQueryToGCSOperator operator that creates files in step 2 to make it simple as error occurs in step 1.

I am calling _get_rowcount function via PythonOperator but it fails when it gets to task3.execute(dict()) and errors out with following message.

```
    task3.execute(dict())
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/bigquery.py", line 663, in execute
    context['task_instance'].xcom_push(key='job_id', value=job_id)
KeyError: 'task_instance'
```

My default_args has 'provide_context': True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on execute the operator supposed to get context but you are sending an empty dict.

my suggestion is to get context in _get_rowcount(**context) and sent in task3.execute

Comment: Made following changes:
```
def _get_rowcount(**context):
    ti = context.get('ti') 

    ..............other code.....

        task3.execute(ti)
```
        -------------------
getting Error

        task3.execute(ti)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/bigquery.py", line 663, in execute
    context['task_instance'].xcom_push(key='job_id', value=job_id)
TypeError: 'TaskInstance' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Pass context to task3 not ti. Context is a dict. ti is TaskInstance

Comment: task3.execute(context) worked. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fix your code, you can try providing the context to `task3` as proposed in the other answer:

```py
def _get_rowcount(ti, **context):

    table_size = 1000000

    rowcount = ti.xcom_pull(key='row_count', task_ids='_bq_result')
    print('BQ rowcount is:', rowcount[0][0])    
    
    for x in range(0,rowcount[0][0],table_size):
        print('Iteration is:', x)
     
        SQL =  f"Create or Replace table <project_id>.<dataset>.<table_name> as select * from `<project_id>.<dataset>.<table_name>` where row_count > {x} and row_count <= { (table_size + x)} "
        print ("SQL: " + SQL)

        task3 = BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator(
            task_id = f"create_tmp_table_{x}",
            use_legacy_sql = False,
            sql = SQL,
            gcp_conn_id = GCP_CONN_ID
        )

        task3.execute({**context, "task_instance": task3, "ti": task3}) # you need to override the task_instance reference and provide the task itself

task2 = PythonOperator(
    task_id = '_get_rowcount',
    provide_context = True,
    python_callable = _get_rowcount,
    dag = dag
    )

task2
```

But in this method your code will be sequential without any parallelism, it will restart all the tasks when a task fails, and you will not have a good monitoring. But if you have Airflow >= 2.3.0, you can use the [Dynamic Task Mapping](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.0/concepts/dynamic-task-mapping.html) feature to create the tasks dynamically:

```py
class MyBigQueryExecuteQueryOperator(BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator):
  def __init__(x, **kwargs):
    table_size = 1000000
    SQL =  f"Create or Replace table <project_id>.<dataset>.<table_name> as select * from `<project_id>.<dataset>.<table_name>` where row_count > {x} and row_count <= { (table_size + x)} "
    super().__init__(sql=SQL, **kwargs)

@task
def inputs_prep(ti, **context):
    rowcount = ti.xcom_pull(key='row_count', task_ids='_bq_result')
    table_size = 1000000
    return [x for x in range(0,rowcount[0][0],table_size)]

task2_inputs = inputs_prep()

task2 = BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator.partial(
    task_id="create_tmp_table",
    max_active_tis_per_dag=16 # to control the parallel copies of the mapped task
).expand(
    x=task2_inputs
)
```